# Rails: disable input tag upon selection from a dropdown menu

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, drop-down-menu, ruby-on-rails-5

**Scenario/Context**

I've got a drop down menu with two input elements underneath.

From the dropdown menu, are names of companies (with values set to the respective company id's), and another prompt to *Add a new company*.

**If the option to *Add a new company*** is selected from the dropdown, then the user is to fill out the 2 input field elements (i.e. company name and company email).

**Otherwise**, if an available company is selected from the dropdown,
then the 2 input fields (for company name and email are to be disabled).

**My question**

Is this possible to do without an AJAX call if I want things to happen without a page refresh?
Can anyone suggest some other alternatives??

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is absolutely possible, though you'd need to use some JavaScript to make it happen and load a bit more data to the DOM on the initial page load.

For each `option` in your `company` select dropdown, add a data attribute for the `name` and `email`.

Then, watch that dropdown for the `change` event in JavaScript. Whenever that event is fired, if the `data-company-name` and `data-company-email` attributes are defined for the selected option, disable the input fields and populate them with those values. If those data attributes are not defined for the option (likely only for your 'Add a new company' option), then clear the values from the input fields and enable them.

Comment: Thanks for the response @s_dolan!
I ended up getting things to work out in the end, without an AJAX call nor an event listener.
I simply used JS to fetch the appropriate DOM elements (based element Id's), and then moved forward from there.
Guaranteed there's a more elegant solution but for now, this will do. :)